# Display \vdash like \models

Tags: symbols, fontsize

I prefer to use `\models` over `\vDash`, but I cannot find an alternative symbol for `\vdash` that has the same size as `\models`. I've looked around here, but I did not manage to find anything. When I typeset the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    $\models\vDash\vdash$
\end{document}
```

I get this result:
[image: \models\vDash\vdash]

**How can I make the `\vdash` symbol the same size as `\models`?**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` in order to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: request for information ... is there a difference in meaning between the two forms, or is it simply personal preference regarding the appearance/size?

Comment: It's merely a personal preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `\model` command which has the same structure of `\models`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\model{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\mkern-.5mu\mathrel{-}}
```

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\model{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\mkern-.5mu\mathrel{-}}

\begin{document}

\[\models\model\]

\end{document}
```

P.S. The definition of `\models` in `fontmath.ltx` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\models{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\mathrel{=}}
```